# pact verifier is failing with Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: pact, pact-python

i am able to mock using mock service as below but when i try to verify the mock against the provider, it is throwing error. i am suspecting because of date values.can you please help me what might be the issue

Mock Jason file :

@Mattthew - Thank you for looking into it . i have cleaned up mock up by re running the mock . instead of mocking total service response, i did mock only one item.

**Mocking Code** :

```
'url = 'http://localhost:1234'
        expected = {'class': 'HealthCheck'}
```

**Mock JSON** :

```
'{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "consumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "provider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request for the health check",
      "providerState": "the health of the system is OK",
      "request": {
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
        },
        "body": {
          "class": "HealthCheck"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}'
```

**Real Service Provider Response** :

```
'{
"class": [
"HealthCheck"
],
"properties": {
"timestamp": "2018-08-01T00:10:00+0000",
"systemName": "Test",
"buildInfo": {
"buildDate": "2018-07-27T07:38:19+0000",
"appVersion": "1111",
"revision": "2 ",
"branch": "develop"
},
"health": "OK",
"checks": []
},
"links": [
{
"rel": [
"self"
],
"href": " check"
}
]
}'
```

**Error when i running against real provider :**
*1) Verifying a pact between consumer and provider Given the health of the system is OK a request for the  check with GET / returns a response which has a matching body
     **Failure/Error: expect(response_body).to match_term expected_response_body, diff_options
     Encoding::UndefinedConversionError:
       "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8***

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this line?

```
"name": "consumer"`enter code here`
```

What is the stuff inside the back ticks? It doesn't appear to be valid JSON - did you modify it by hand?

Also, not sure it's intentional, but there also appears to be a lot of unnecessary spaces in your values. Might be worth checking that too.

Comment: @Mattthew - Thank you for looking into it . i have cleaned up mock up by re running the mock . instead of mocking total service response, i did mock only one item.

but still getting same error from real provider side .

Comment: if real service response is huge, can i mock only item(expected = {'class': 'HealthCheck'}) which i mentioned above in Mock Code  . can you please help me what i am doing wrong

Comment: just want to make sure real service is repsonding with  "class": [
"HealthCheck"
] then i want to pass the test

Comment: Maybe join the conversation in slack.pact.io. this isn't the right place for this feedback